# While trying to compile maven build getting this error

Tags: maven, cucumber, appium, maven-dependency, appium-java

Error

```java
Failed to collect dependencies at com.sikulix:sikulixapi:jar:1.1.0 -> jxgrabkey:jxgrabkey:jar:1.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for jxgrabkey:jxgrabkey:jar:1.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved: jxgrabkey:jxgrabkey:pom:1.0 (present, but unavailable): Could not transfer artifact jxgrabkey:jxgrabkey:pom:1.0 from/to seeetest (https://cloud.experitest.com/repo/): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
```

I tried to run a bdd-cucumber mobile automation test framework , while compiling the build using mvn compile command getting build failure.